# if AND then else statement

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010, crystal-reports-xi

I am a self taught beginner. I am looking to get additional {billing.items} that will only show when standard {billing.items} are present. Then if not present, just get the standard. I am using an IF AND THEN ELSE statement. Nothing is being returned from the beginning IF AND THEN, I am only getting the ELSE.

when i make a simple IF THEN statement with the entire list, i and getting all data. So the data does exist. But i need the additional items to be dependent on if the standard items are present. I am stumped.

`( 
if ({billing.items} in [1244, 1245, 1246, 1247, 1248, 1249, 1250]
and {billing.items} in [1296, 2390, 2391, 2392, 2393]) then true
else 
{billing.items} in [1244, 1245, 1246, 1247, 1248, 1249, 1250] 
)`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to check if at least one item of each list is available.

Crystal Reports always looks at the formula on a record basis.
So `{billing.items}` is always evaluated as the value of the current record and thus the statment will always be `false` as `{billing.items}` only contains one value.

To solve this, you can create three separate formulas one with the first list and one with the second list. In the third formula (or suppression formula) you can check if the "Maximum" of each list-formula on the report is `true`.

**Formula "@List1"**

```
{billing.items} in [1244, 1245, 1246, 1247, 1248, 1249, 1250]
```

**Formula "@List2"**

```
{billing.items} in [1296, 2390, 2391, 2392, 2393]
```

**Check**

```
if Maximum({@List1})=true and Maximum({@List2})=true then
    // Standard-Items are present
else
    // Standard-Items are NOT present
```

Comment: Sorry if that was a confusing explanation! Yes, I want to check that one item from both are present, but if this is not the case, then I want only the "standard" list. I actually want one list to be dependent on the other, I think we are saying the same thing and that this will work. I will try it out!

Comment: Yes, I think we're talking about the same thing. My wording was confusing too, so I've tried to improve it now :-)